# Apply regex to create new column - isdigit() vs isnumeric()

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like shown below

```
data_file= pd.DataFrame({'pid':[1,1.5,6.557657,'ABCD','1+','TRACE']})
```

It looks like as shown below

[image]

What I would like to have is create two new columns `value_as_number` and `value_as_string`

This is what I tried

```
value_as_string = data_file['pid'].str.extract('(\D+)') # this chops of the `1` from `1+` which isn't expected.
```

The output for `value_as_string` is as shown below

[image]

```
value_as_number = ~data_file['pid'].str.extract('(\D+)') # results in error as shown below

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'
```

I also tried but it doesn't help either

```
data_file['pid'].str.isnumeric()
data_file['pid'].str.digit()
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below. Seperate column for numbers (like 1,2,1.5,4.5) and seperate column for mix of number,characters and symbols (1+,ABCD, test) etc

[image]

Comment: The dataframe you provided now has mixed datatypes. It has integers, floats and strings. Is that also the case in your actual dataset? It's easier if you only had strings

Comment: I think maybe testing the value via `.str.contains()` rather than extracting substring values could be a better approach. Maybe something like testing if the value contains anything other than digits and a period, and if it does, assuming the value is a string? e.g., if `data_file['pid'].str.contains(pat='[^\d.]', regex=True)` returns `True` then treat it as a string, if it returns `False` then treat it as a number.

Comment: It has mixed datatypes in my real data as well.

Comment: Will try your suggestion @AFewMistakesAgo

Comment: If the value contains more than one period, would you want it treated as a numeric or a string? My proposal above would treat it as a numeric, which I think is not correct. E.g., `1..1` would be treated as a numeric, as would '192.168.0.1` etc. Perhaps one of the suggested answers would be better.

Comment: Does any of the answers under this question answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598770/expected-behavior-of-pandas-str-isnumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if need distinguish numeric values vs strings in mixed types use `isinstance`:

```
data_file= pd.DataFrame({'pid':[1,1.5,6.557657,'ABCD','1+','TRACE']})

mask = data_file['pid'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (float, int)))

data_file['value_as_number'] = data_file['pid'].where(mask)
data_file['value_as_string'] = data_file['pid'].mask(mask)
print (data_file)
       pid value_as_number value_as_string
0        1               1             NaN
1      1.5             1.5             NaN
2  6.55766         6.55766             NaN
3     ABCD             NaN            ABCD
4       1+             NaN              1+
5    TRACE             NaN           TRACE
```

If all values are strings one possible solution is use pattern in [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test integers and floats:

```
mask = data_file['pid'].astype(str).str.contains('^\d+$|^\d+\.\d+$')
```

Or custom function for test numeric:

```
def test(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

mask = data_file['pid'].apply(test)
```

Comment: Here, you are trying to find whether the element is float or int. What if I would like to find whether they are string or not? `data_file['pid'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (object)))`, it returns True for all elements

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` and `df.where`

```
data_file['num'] = pd.to_numeric(data_file['pid'],errors='coerce')

data_file['alpha'] = data_file['pid'].where(data_file['num'].isnull())

       pid       num  alpha
0        1  1.000000    NaN
1      1.5  1.500000    NaN
2  6.55766  6.557657    NaN
3     ABCD       NaN   ABCD
4       1+       NaN     1+
5    TRACE       NaN  TRACE
```

At the end you can use `fillna('')` but try not to do it for the numeric column.

Comment: Will try your answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex. The following code will get you what you want, but you will get columns of `object`s.

```
import pandas as pd

data_file = pd.DataFrame({'pid':[1,1.5,6.557657,'ABCD','1+','TRACE']})
data_file['numbers'] = data_file['pid'].map(lambda x: x if type(x) in [int, float] else '')
data_file['strings'] = data_file['pid'].map(lambda s: s if type(s) is str else '')
```

And this is the output:

```
        pid  numbers strings
0        1        1
1      1.5      1.5
2  6.55766  6.55766
3     ABCD             ABCD
4       1+               1+
5    TRACE            TRACE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.replace` & `str.isnumeric`:

```
m1 = data_file['pid'].astype(str).str.replace('.', '', n=1).str.isnumeric()
m2 = ~m1

data_file['value_as_number'] = data_file['pid'].where(m1)
data_file['value_as_string'] = data_file['pid'].where(m2)
```

**Output**

```
         pid value_as_number value_as_string
0          1               1             NaN
1        1.5             1.5             NaN
2    6.55766         6.55766             NaN
3       ABCD             NaN            ABCD
4         1+             NaN              1+
5      TRACE             NaN           TRACE
6  1.212.333             NaN       1.212.333
7     1....1             NaN          1....1
```

Comment: Wouldn't this suffer from the same potential issue as my suggestion -- it would treat `1...1` as a number, and `192.168.0.1` etc as a number?

Comment: Good point, added `n=1` so it will only replace a decimal @AFewMistakesAgo , see edit with extra data